# Error using Javascript and JSP, string with space gives `Unterminated string literal`

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to pass a string value to JavaScript from JSP page.
I am using

```
display("<%=name%>")
```

It works fine but when i have string like `'sweet milk'`, JavaScript throws the error

> Unterminated string literal

How to solve this?

Comment: Please show a full code block.

Comment: Maybe it is better to post part of your code

Answer (score 2):

Your string contains single quotes - you can escape single quotes as "\x27" and double quotes as "\x22" and then pass it to javascript.

Comment: where to pass this, can u explain it

Comment: you could do a string replace, replacing single quotes with \x27 and double quotes with \x22, this modified string is then your `name` value for display. Since you work with Java server side I'd recommend `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript` though as suggested by @JB Nizet

Answer (score 1):

You probably have characters in your String that should be escaped in Javascript. For example, if your string is `My name is "John"`, your code will generate

```
var a = "My name is "John"";
```

which is invalid.

You should use StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript from commons-lang to make sure everything is correctly escaped (single and double quotes, newlines, tabs, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's an error in the generated JavaScript code. Is there any way to look at you page? I suggest to look at the generated source code of that page.